# button share in facebook is not work

Tags: facebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtPEL.png)When I share a status of my website in facebook, it doesn't work, it displays this message : 
  "Unable to load this URL: The domain of this URL is not registered in the URL of the application. To be able to import this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your application to the Application Settings Fields field."

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your website domain to the application there:

[image]

Comment: i add my siteweb domain, but the same problem, App domains: www.ppollit.com and site URL: https://www.ppollit/survey/%7B%7Bsurvey._id%7D%7D

Comment: the "site url" needs to be the root uri, so ppollit.com